# Providing synchronous and asynchronous versions of an API in library code

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Is there a recommended best practices/guidance for exposing synchronous and asynchronous versions of an API in  a class library? For instance, if I have the following 2 methods defined in a class library:

```
  public Task<string> GetSomeDataAsync()
    {
        //typically an IO operation that would be awaited on, simplified to return a Task for illustration
        return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew( () =>  "foo");
    }

    public string GetSomeDataSync()
    {
        var task = GetSomeDataAsync();
        task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        return task.Result;
    }
```

The above could be hosted in a Winform/WPF/Console/ASP.NET client app.
Is it safe for a client to use the synchronous version above which uses task.Result, given that the task is configured not to capture any synchronization context to avoid potential deadlocks

Answer (score 5):

I think the best advice on this comes from two articles by Stephen Toub:

- [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)
- [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

The second one is more relevant for you. In short, it says that you shouldn't do this. If the caller of your method decides to wait synchronously, he still can make that choice and he is in a better position than you to do it (because he knows the environment, so he should know if deadlocks are an issue, for example).

> The above could be hosted in a Winform/WPF/Console/ASP.NET client app. Is it safe for a client to use the synchronous version above which uses task.Result, given that the task is configured not to capture any synchronization context to avoid potential deadlocks

You're wrong about that. [`ConfigureAwait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) doesn't modify the `Task` in any way (especially since the `Task` is already executing at that point). All it does is to return a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` and if you `await` that, it won't resume on the captured context.

This means your method would still deadlock.

Comment: That is great advise, the second link was especially useful! For ASP.NET apps, does this mean making your web pages async?

Comment: @AbhijeetPatel Yeah, if it makes sense for you. I don't think everything has to be async though, especially if it means rewriting existing code.

Comment: @svik: The problem is that the client is ultimately calling into an HTTP REST service using the HttpClient API. The only option to get data is using the GetAsync methods in the  HttpClient API(there is no synchronous version). This (as we know) makes all the callers upstream async as well. Hence my original question on providing a "sync" version of which essentially peforms a blocking call via task.Wait() or task.Result. My thought was that if the synchronization context is not captured, you would not run into threading issues but your client thread would indeed be blocked. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 "major" options for async patterns which are endorsed by MS. I'd recommend that you pick one of the patterns and adhere to it... It looks like you're already headed towards the "Task-based Asynchronous Pattern" so you'd have very few mods in order to conform to the pattern. This allows you to create your methods in a way that will be uniform and intuitive to other consumers... They'll know the pattern from the .NET libraries that MS has built. See this for details:

**Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx**

**Task Async Pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx**

An example of your methods using the Task Asynchronous Pattern with support for cancellation tokens:

```
public Task<string> GetSomeDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
{
    return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>  "foo", cancellationToken);
}

// NOTE: no need to append Sync to the method name, redundant.
public string GetSomeData()
{
    var task = GetSomeDataAsync();
    task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    return task.Result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question, you don't address having the two methods at all.